# Always echo a number of cells which is a multiple of 5 in table (php)

Tags: php, html, css

What I'm trying to do is when I input a number, it will display the table with 5 value in 1 row. But the problem that I facing is when I input as 67, it doesn't look like what I want.  What I want is always echo a number of cells which is a multiple of 5.

Here's is the output suppose like this, but my output only show until 67, it doesn't show the rest empty cell in table:

[image: Here's is the output suppose like this, but my output only show until 67, it doesn't show the rest empty cell in table]

Here's is my code for input html:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
<form action = "shownumber.php" method="POST">
<label>Please input the maximum number : </label><input type="number" name="Max_number" required size="20">&nbsp;&nbsp;<input type="submit"  name="submit" onclick="print_number($Max_number)"/>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Here's is my code for php file:

```
<table>
<?php
$Max_number = $_POST["Max_number"];
function print_number($Max_number)
{
$x=1;
for ($col=1; $col <= 5; $col++) {
if($x <= $Max_number){
echo "<td>" . $x . "</td>";
$x++;
}
else
echo "<td></td>";
}
}
print_number($Max_number);
?>
</table>
```

Can someone help me to solve this issue? Thanks.

Comment: It's a bit unclear what you mean by "empty" cells. Are you saying it should always echo a number of cells which is a multiple of 5?

Comment: yes, this is what I want.

Comment: The code you have only has a loop from 1 to 5, it also doesn't output any row tags.  So not sure how this generates the output that you say you get.

Comment: @StevenKhoo please shows output what you want is?

Comment: @StevenKhoo Note that in the `onclick` part, the string `$Max_number` is printed, not the value. You can use `<?php echo $Max_number; ?>` instead.

Comment: @noam that won't help because `print_number` is a PHP function, so it'll still crash. Anyway it makes no sense to use onclick, the form will post back to PHP when it's submitted already, without that. The whole onclick can just be removed, it's not possible to call a PHP function directly from a click event in that way.

Comment: @ADyson, unless there's also a JS function named `print_number` (which I assumed). But if not, then of course this won't help.

Comment: @noam true but based on what's shown in the question that would be unlikely I think.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `shownumber.php` should probably look like this:

```php
<table>
<?php
function print_number($Max_number) {
        $x = 1;
        while ($x <= $Max_number) {
                echo "<tr>";
                for ($col=1; $col <= 5; $col++) {
                        echo ($x <= $Max_number)
                                ? "<td>{$x}</td>"
                                : '<td></td>';
                        $x ++;
                }
                echo "</tr>";
        }
}
print_number($_POST["Max_number"] ?? 0);
?>
</table>
```

1. You should use `<tr>` to quote all rows.
2. You should continuously printing rows until the max number is reached (see the while loop).

Some other code-style improvements:

1. The global `$Max_number=$_POST["Max_number"]` is not needed if you can simply use `$_POST["Max_number"]` as the function argument.
2. Simplified your if-then statement into [ternary operator](https://www.php.net/ternary#language.operators.comparison.ternary) to keep things clean and short.
3. Used [null coalesce operator](https://www.php.net/manual/en/migration70.new-features.php#migration70.new-features.null-coalesce-op) `$_POST["Max_number"] ?? 0` to prevent error if the form submission is not correct.

Answer (score 2):

Your current code will only ever print numbers up to 5, and no more, because of the fixed `for` loop.

That loop is fine for printing the right number of columns, but to print multiple rows you'll need to loop outside that.

This version calculates the number of rows needed (by dividing by the number of desired columns) and then loops to print the correct number of each:

```
function print_number($Max_number)
{
    $cols = 5;
    $rows = ceil($Max_number / $cols);
    $num = 1;

    for ($row = 1; $row <= $rows; $row++)
    {
        echo "<tr>";
        for ($col = 1; $col <= $cols; $col++) {
            echo "<td>";
            if($num <= $Max_number) echo $num++;
            echo "</td>";
        }
        echo "</tr>";
   }
}
```

Demo: http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/5fd70054b44053bebc6ba0819111d6c12544481b

Also `onclick="print_number($Max_number)"` in your HTML can be removed (because 1. your form will post back successfully without this and 2. you can't call PHP functions from JavaScript in this way anyway).